# How to set integer value on label?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to set a `integer` datatype value on `label` (data type `string`).

I used `"setText"` method nut it display an error.

Answer (score 2):

Not only for integers , [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class have `valueOf` methods for almost all data types

```
String.valueOf(int);
```

Ex

```
label.setText(String.valueOf(5));  //example 5.Place your integer.
```

Reference : Check Oracle  docs on  [Converting Strings to Numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
label.setText(String.valueOf(intValue));
label.setText(Integer.toString(intValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

`label.setText(intValue+"");`
Will do the trick.

Comment: Why use a hack like this when String.valueOf() exists?